# Validate Fields in React using yup

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, yup

How do I put a validation in yup that at least two fields are required?

Pls check codesandbox here [Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-and-yup-simple-demo-forked-lr4ty?file=/src/index.js)

```
const validationSearch = yup.object().shape({
  instagramProfileId: yup
    .string()
    .when(["$tiktokProfileId", "$youtubeProfileId"], {
      is: (tiktokProfileId, youtubeProfileId) =>
        tiktokProfileId && youtubeProfileId,
      then: yup.string().notRequired(),
      otherwise: yup.string().required()
    }),
  tiktokProfileId: yup
    .string()
    .when(["$instagramProfileId", "$youtubeProfileId"], {
      is: (instagramProfileId, youtubeProfileId) =>
        instagramProfileId && youtubeProfileId,
      then: yup.string().notRequired(),
      otherwise: yup.string().required()
    }),
  youtubeProfileId: yup
    .string()
    .when(["$instagramProfileId", "$tiktokProfileId"], {
      is: (instagramProfileId, tiktokProfileId) =>
        instagramProfileId && tiktokProfileId,
      then: yup.string().notRequired(),
      otherwise: yup.string().required()
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your validationSearch function by :

**Delete all '$' and add an array at the end with the fields you need in each "when" condition**

```
const validationSearch = yup.object().shape(
  {
    instagramProfileId: yup
      .string()
      .when(["tiktokProfileId", "youtubeProfileId"], {
        is: (tiktokProfileId, youtubeProfileId) =>
          tiktokProfileId && youtubeProfileId,
        then: yup.string().notRequired(),
        otherwise: yup.string().required()
      }),
    tiktokProfileId: yup
      .string()
      .when(["instagramProfileId", "youtubeProfileId"], {
        is: (instagramProfileId, youtubeProfileId) =>
          instagramProfileId && youtubeProfileId,
        then: yup.string().notRequired(),
        otherwise: yup.string().required()
      }),
    youtubeProfileId: yup
      .string()
      .when(["instagramProfileId", "tiktokProfileId"], {
        is: (instagramProfileId, tiktokProfileId) =>
          instagramProfileId && tiktokProfileId,
        then: yup.string().notRequired(),
        otherwise: yup.string().required()
      })
  },
  [
    ["tiktokProfileId", "youtubeProfileId"],
    ["instagramProfileId", "youtubeProfileId"],
    ["instagramProfileId", "tiktokProfileId"]
  ]
);
```

**Demo** : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fmsdlv?file=src%2FApp.js)